# Unable to set sensitivity label on spreadsheet

Tags: c#, label

I'm attempting to set a sensitivity label on a spreadsheet using MIPS (Microsoft Information Protection) as follows:

```
// Create a file handler for the file
var handler = Task.Run(async () => await fileEngine.CreateFileHandlerAsync(stream, filename, true)).Result;

// Set Labeling Options
LabelingOptions labelingOptions = new LabelingOptions()
{
    JustificationMessage = "Programmatically set",
    AssignmentMethod = AssignmentMethod.Standard,
    ExtendedProperties = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
};

// Set a label on input file
handler.SetLabel(labelObj, labelingOptions, new ProtectionSettings());

// Commit changes, save as outputFilePath
var result = Task.Run(async () => await handler.CommitAsync(outStream)).Result;
```

I am able to see all labels, and if i take one and set it using SetLabel it comes back true (result = true) and the file size changes but if i save to file and open it, there is no label set. I also can not see the label set on other documents created where i manually set a label in Excel.

Anyone know what the issue might be or if there is another way to set sensitivity labels on documents?

Comment: Turns out i was setting labels on a test tenant, but opening the document locally, those labels don't exist on the local tenant, so they are not displayed in Word app.